# How to get Day name in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to get the name of the day from date in Google BigQuery.

I can achieve this by below query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=1 THEN 'Sunday' WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=2 THEN 'Monday'
             WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=3 THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=4 THEN 'Wednesday'
             WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=5 THEN 'Thusday' WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=6 THEN 'Friday'
             WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())=7 THEN 'Saturday' END as [DOW]
```

If there is any default function available to get name of the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. According to the docs on [query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) (which you should bookmark :) ), most specifically the [DateTime ones](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions) .

You can get the number of the day with DAYOFWEEK(), as you have in your query. But that's it.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, there are equivalent functions in both, standardSQL and legacySQL.

### Standard SQL

You can use the FORMAT_DATE() function where you can use any date format you'd like.
[Link to Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_date)

Example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  CURRENT_DATE() AS date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', CURRENT_DATE()) AS dow
```

### Legacy SQL

There is the STRFTIME_UTC_USEC() function. It requires converting your timestamp to USEC first though. [Link to docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#strftime_utc_usec)

Example:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  CURRENT_DATE() AS date,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())), '%A') AS dow
```

Comment: With legacy SQL you can actually do it simpler: `SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS date, STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(CURRENT_DATE(), '%A') AS dow`

Answer (score 4):

In Google's Big Query, the function to use is: format_datetime('%A',yourdate)
instead of format_date as posted in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **Medur Mamutov above**. One can leverage the [format_date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) function and leverage the different [formatting elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date).

For the full weekday name try:
`SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%A", CURRENT_DATE())`